# systemctl & Oracle Linux 9 & curl

Tags: systemd

I've a Oracle Linux 9 (this a Red Hat "clone") and have a systemctl service which should execute a curl at startup. And I'm getting this error:

```
× gitlab-runner-curl.service - gitlab runner curl
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner-curl.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-05-09 16:51:31 CEST; 27s ago
    Process: 998 ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl -v -k --fail -F token=glptt-35a1ab49139cf38005a38d547ae614cba7c28862 -F ref=acc-mi-1 https>
   Main PID: 998 (code=exited, status=6)
        CPU: 23ms

May 09 16:51:31 serverx systemd[1]: Starting gitlab runner curl...
May 09 16:51:31 serverx curl[998]:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
May 09 16:51:31 serverx curl[998]:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
May 09 16:51:31 serverx curl[998]: [121B blob data]
May 09 16:51:31 serverx curl[998]: * Closing connection 0
May 09 16:51:31 serverx curl[998]: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: servery
May 09 16:51:31 serverx systemd[1]: gitlab-runner-curl.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=6/NOTCONFIGURED
May 09 16:51:31 serverx systemd[1]: gitlab-runner-curl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 09 16:51:31 serverx systemd[1]: Failed to start gitlab runner curl
```

So apparently it's executing before the network has been started (because of the `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: servery` error).
Why is this?
This is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gitlab runner curl
After=gitlab-runner.service network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=gitlab-runner
ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl -v -k --fail -F token=xxxxxx -F ref=acc-mi-1 https://servery/api/v4/projects/128/trigger/pipeline
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see the service should start after network.start.
The curl statement runs perfectly from the shell.

regards,

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe using `After=network.target` waits until after the network is online.  It would cause the service to be run anytime after `network.target` was initiated, but not necessarily when the network is online and available for connections.

According to [the documentation about the various `network*.target` units](https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE/) you probably want to use `network-online.target` in your service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gitlab runner curl
After=gitlab-runner.service network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
```

Comment: Thanks! spot on: network-online.target did indeed solve the issue